# Intersection and union of ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, list, union, intersection

Are there any methods to do so? I was looking but couldn't find any.

Another question: I need these methods so I can filter files. 
Some are `AND` filters and some are `OR` filters (like in set theory), so I need to filter according to all files and the unite/intersects ArrayLists that holds those files.

Should I use a different data structure to hold the files? Is there anything else that would offer a better runtime?

Comment: If you didn't want to creayte a new list, Vector.retainAll(Vector) trims your orignal vector to only the intersection with second vector.

Comment: @user2808054 why `Vector`? That class has been discouraged since Java 1.2.

Comment: @dimo414 an interface which I'm using (I have no option) returns things as vectors. I didn't know it had been discouraged ! Thanks for the info .. Discouraged by who ? I haven't seen any note about it being deprecated so this is a surprise

Comment: From the Javadocs: "[*As of the Java 2 platform v1.2 ... it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)". The only time you *might* need `Vector` is for cross-thread interactions, but there are safer data structures for those use cases too. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/113632). Any library still using `Vector` in 2016 is very suspect in my opinion.

Comment: @dimo414 it's an IBM library, haha! (Lotus Domino data api). Thanks for the info, very helpful

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Here's a plain implementation without using any third-party library. Main advantage over `retainAll`, `removeAll` and `addAll` is that these methods don't modify the original lists input to the methods.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("B", "C", "D", "E", "F"));

        System.out.println(new Test().intersection(list1, list2));
        System.out.println(new Test().union(list1, list2));
    }

    public <T> List<T> union(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();

        set.addAll(list1);
        set.addAll(list2);

        return new ArrayList<T>(set);
    }

    public <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (T t : list1) {
            if(list2.contains(t)) {
                list.add(t);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can create new list with list1 elements and then call retainAll, addAll methods

Comment: why you using strictfp in this solution?

Comment: Should use a `HashSet` for `intersection` so that the average case performance is O(n) instead of O(n^2).

Comment: This post could use an update to demonstrate the benefits of the Java 8 Stream API.

Comment: I get error When I try assign this value  ->  Example :    ArrayList<String> total  total = (ArrayList<String>) intersection(list2, list1)   --->cannot cast java.util.arraylist to java.util.arraylist<string>

Comment: Better use the Constructor [`HashSet(int initialCapacity)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet-int-).

Comment: As @Zong mentioned Set will perform much better especially in larger collections. I added my answer as not only using Set but also with more generic Collection signature. http://stackoverflow.com/a/59476700/2290369

Comment: for collection of Objects, it's nice to override the equals() and  hashCode() methods for custom objects

Answer (score 136):

[Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) (so ArrayList also) have:

```
col.retainAll(otherCol) // for intersection
col.addAll(otherCol) // for union
```

Use a List implementation if you accept repetitions, a Set implementation if you don't:

```
Collection<String> col1 = new ArrayList<String>(); // {a, b, c}
// Collection<String> col1 = new TreeSet<String>();
col1.add("a");
col1.add("b");
col1.add("c");

Collection<String> col2 = new ArrayList<String>(); // {b, c, d, e}
// Collection<String> col2 = new TreeSet<String>();
col2.add("b");
col2.add("c");
col2.add("d");
col2.add("e");

col1.addAll(col2);
System.out.println(col1); 
//output for ArrayList: [a, b, c, b, c, d, e]
//output for TreeSet: [a, b, c, d, e]
```

Comment: There's been a suggested edit that this union *"is incorrect since it will contain common elements twice"*. The edit recommended to use a `HashSet` instead.

Comment: Actually it was edited, see: "Use a List implementation if you accept repetitions, a Set implementation if you don't:"

Comment: No, retainAll is not intersection for list.  In above, all elements in col that are not in otherCol are removed.  Let's say otherCol is {a,b,b,c} and col is {b,b,b,c,d}.  Then col ends up with {b,b,b,c} which is not the strictly the intersection of the two.  I would expect that to be {b,b,c}.  A different operation is being performed.

Comment: I also don't see how `addAll()` is union for lists; it's just concatenating the second list onto the end of the first. A union operation would avoid adding an element if the first list already contains it.

Answer (score 91):

This post is fairly old, but nevertheless it was the first one popping up on google when looking for that topic.

I want to give an update using Java 8 streams doing (basically) the same thing in a single line:

```
List<T> intersect = list1.stream()
    .filter(list2::contains)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<T> union = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If anyone has a better/faster solution let me know, but this solution is a nice one liner that can be easily included in a method without adding a unnecessary helper class/method and still keep the readability.

Comment: Ooof, it might be a nice one-liner but it takes O(n^2) time. Convert one of the lists to a `Set` then use the set's `contains` method. Not everything in life has to be done with streams.

Answer (score 36):

```
list1.retainAll(list2) - is intersection
```

union will be `removeAll` and then `addAll`.

Find more in the documentation of collection(ArrayList is a collection)
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Comment: Both `retainAll()` and `removeAll()` are O(n^2) operations on lists. We can do better.

Comment: I up voted but now I have a question. `retainAll` of {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5} over {1, 2, 3} results in {1, 2, 2, 3}. Shouldn't it be {1, 2, 3} to be the intersection?

Comment: @ghchoi the semantic behind list and set is now the issue. Using list [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5] we accept duplicate but for the set {1, 2, 3} duplicate are not allowed. Also two notation are different in general but not fixed, for list [...duplicate is a feature...] and for set {...not duplicate is allowed...}

Answer (score 22):

Unions and intersections defined only for sets, not lists. As you mentioned.

Check [guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki) library for filters. Also guava provides real [intersections and unions](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html)

```
 static <E> Sets.SetView<E >union(Set<? extends E> set1, Set<? extends E> set2)
 static <E> Sets.SetView<E> intersection(Set<E> set1, Set<?> set2)
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use `CollectionUtils` from [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html).

Comment: In case someone finds this answer a bit too short: 'CollectionUtils.containsAny' and 'CollectionUtils.containsAll' are the methods.

Comment: it's weird that CollectionUtils from apache commons does not support generics

Comment: For Union: `CollectionUtils.union(collection1, collection2);` and for Intersection: `CollectionUtils.intersection(collection1, collection2);`

Answer (score 8):

The solution marked is not efficient. It has a O(n^2) time complexity. What we can do is to sort both lists, and the execute an intersection algorithm as the one below.

```
private  static ArrayList<Integer> interesect(ArrayList<Integer> f, ArrayList<Integer> s) { 
    ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int i = 0, j = 0; 
    while (i != f.size() && j != s.size()) { 

        if (f.get(i) < s.get(j)) {
            i ++;
        } else if (f.get(i) > s.get(j)) { 
            j ++;
        } else { 
            res.add(f.get(i)); 
            i ++;  j ++;
        }
    }


    return res; 
}
```

This one has a complexity of O(n log n + n) which is in O(n log n). 
The union is done in a similar manner. Just make sure you make the suitable modifications on the if-elseif-else statements.

You can also use iterators if you want (I know they are more efficient in C++, I dont know if this is true in Java as well).

Comment: Not generic enough, T may not be Comparable and in some cases comparing is expensive ...

Comment: Not generic, I totally agree. Comparison is expensive? how would you solve that?

Comment: Sadly - it would be cheaper to do it in O(n^2) :)
For Numbers this solution is good...

Comment: Sadly - you did not answer my question. Let me rephrase it, how is O(n^2) better given a comparison function of cost c(n)?

Comment: Why c(n)? Take ArrayList<List<String>>, it will run at O(n*m)*c(n).

Comment: Anyway, the question itself is not correct, you need to define what intersection of lists is. If it's the same as intersection of sets then the better approach would be new List(new Set(list1).retain(new Set(list2))), which is O(n) + O(m) + O(n+m) ~= O(n+m), or even better using SetView in guava...

Comment: Guava? retain? - Sadly, you don't make sense.

Comment: Converting one input to a set and calling `contains()` in a loop (as Devenv is suggestion) would take O(n + m) time. Sorting is needlessly complicated and takes O(n log n + m log n + n) time. Granted that reduces to O(n log n) time, but that's still worse than linear time, and much more complex.

Answer (score 5):

One-liners since **JAVA 8**

## Union

### if there are no duplicates:

```
  return concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).collect(toList());
```

### union and distinct:

```
  return concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).distinct().collect(toList());
```

### union and distinct if Collection/Set return type:

```
  return concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).collect(toSet());
```

## Intersect

### if no duplicates:

```
  return a.stream().filter(b::contains).collect(toList());
```

**PERFORMANCE**: If collection `b` is huge and not O(1), then pre-optimize the filter performance by adding 1 line before `return`: Copy to `HasSet` *(`import java.util.Set;`)*:

> *... b = Set.copyOf(b);*

### intersect and distinct:

```
  return a.stream().distinct().filter(b::contains).collect(toList());
```

### *- imports*

> *import static java.util.stream.Stream.concat;*
> *import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;*
> *import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;*

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use a `Set` to hold the files if you want to do intersection and union on them. Then you can use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [Sets](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) class to do `union`, `intersection` and filtering by a `Predicate` as well. The difference between these methods and the other suggestions is that all of these methods create lazy *views* of the union, intersection, etc. of the two sets. Apache Commons creates a new collection and copies data to it. `retainAll` changes one of your collections by removing elements from it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way how you can do an intersection with streams (remember that you have to use java 8 for streams):

```
List<foo> fooList1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new foo(), new foo()));
List<foo> fooList2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new foo(), new foo()));
fooList1.stream().filter(f -> fooList2.contains(f)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

An example for lists with different types. If you have a realtion between foo and bar and you can get a bar-object from foo than you can modify your stream:

```
List<foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new foo(), new foo()));
List<bar> barList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new bar(), new bar()));

fooList.stream().filter(f -> barList.contains(f.getBar()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use commons-collections4 [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html)

```
Collection<Integer> collection1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8);
Collection<Integer> collection2 = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 6, 8);

Collection<Integer> intersection = CollectionUtils.intersection(collection1, collection2);
System.out.println(intersection); // [2, 4, 8]

Collection<Integer> union = CollectionUtils.union(collection1, collection2);
System.out.println(union); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Collection<Integer> subtract = CollectionUtils.subtract(collection1, collection2);
System.out.println(subtract); // [1, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 3):

- retainAll will modify your list
- Guava doesn't have APIs for List (only for set)

I found ListUtils very useful for this use case.

Use ListUtils from org.apache.commons.collections if you do not want to modify existing list.

`ListUtils.intersection(list1, list2)`

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8, I use simple helper methods like this:

```
public static <T> Collection<T> getIntersection(Collection<T> coll1, Collection<T> coll2){
    return Stream.concat(coll1.stream(), coll2.stream())
            .filter(coll1::contains)
            .filter(coll2::contains)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

public static <T> Collection<T> getMinus(Collection<T> coll1, Collection<T> coll2){
    return coll1.stream().filter(not(coll2::contains)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

public static <T> Predicate<T> not(Predicate<T> t) {
    return t.negate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the objects in the list are hashable (i.e. have a decent hashCode and equals function), the fastest approach between tables approx. size > 20 is to construct a HashSet for the larger of the two lists.

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> intersection(Collection<T> a, Collection<T> b) {
    if (b.size() > a.size()) {
        return intersection(b, a);
    } else {
        if (b.size() > 20 && !(a instanceof HashSet)) {
            a = new HashSet(a);
        }
        ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList();
        for (T objb : b) {
            if (a.contains(objb)) {
                result.add(objb);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also working on the similar situation and reached here searching for help. Ended up finding my own solution for Arrays.
ArrayList AbsentDates = new ArrayList(); // Will Store Array1-Array2

**Note :** Posting this if it can help someone reaching this page for help.

```
ArrayList<String> AbsentDates = new ArrayList<String>();//This Array will store difference
      public void AbsentDays() {
            findDates("April", "2017");//Array one with dates in Month April 2017
            findPresentDays();//Array two carrying some dates which are subset of Dates in Month April 2017

            for (int i = 0; i < Dates.size(); i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < PresentDates.size(); j++) {

                    if (Dates.get(i).equals(PresentDates.get(j))) {

                        Dates.remove(i);
                    }               

                }              
                AbsentDates = Dates;   
            }
            System.out.println(AbsentDates );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Intersection of two list of different object based on common key - Java 8**

```
 private List<User> intersection(List<User> users, List<OtherUser> list) {

        return list.stream()
                .flatMap(OtherUser -> users.stream()
                        .filter(user -> user.getId()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase(OtherUser.getId())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: how about difference set between those 2 list?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T> Set<T> intersectCollections(Collection<T> col1, Collection<T> col2) {
    Set<T> set1, set2;
    if (col1 instanceof Set) {
        set1 = (Set) col1;
    } else {
        set1 = new HashSet<>(col1);
    }

    if (col2 instanceof Set) {
        set2 = (Set) col2;
    } else {
        set2 = new HashSet<>(col2);
    }

    Set<T> intersection = new HashSet<>(Math.min(set1.size(), set2.size()));

    for (T t : set1) {
        if (set2.contains(t)) {
            intersection.add(t);
        }
    }

    return intersection;
}
```

**JDK8+ (Probably Best Performance)**

```
public static <T> Set<T> intersectCollections(Collection<T> col1, Collection<T> col2) {
    boolean isCol1Larger = col1.size() > col2.size();
    Set<T> largerSet;
    Collection<T> smallerCol;

    if (isCol1Larger) {
        if (col1 instanceof Set) {
            largerSet = (Set<T>) col1;
        } else {
            largerSet = new HashSet<>(col1);
        }
        smallerCol = col2;
    } else {
        if (col2 instanceof Set) {
            largerSet = (Set<T>) col2;
        } else {
            largerSet = new HashSet<>(col2);
        }
        smallerCol = col1;
    }

    return smallerCol.stream()
            .filter(largerSet::contains)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

If you don't care about performance and prefer smaller code just use:

```
col1.stream().filter(col2::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

retainAll() method use for finding common element..i.e;intersection
list1.retainAll(list2)

Answer (score 0):

First, I am copying all values of arrays into a single array then I am removing duplicates values into the array. Line 12, explaining if same number occur more than time then put some extra garbage value into "j" position. At the end, traverse from start-end and check if same garbage value occur then discard.

```
public class Union {
public static void main(String[] args){

    int arr1[]={1,3,3,2,4,2,3,3,5,2,1,99};
    int arr2[]={1,3,2,1,3,2,4,6,3,4};
    int arr3[]=new int[arr1.length+arr2.length];

    for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
        arr3[i]=arr1[i];

    for(int i=0;i<arr2.length;i++)
        arr3[arr1.length+i]=arr2[i];
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3));

    for(int i=0;i<arr3.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<arr3.length;j++)
        {
            if(arr3[i]==arr3[j])
                arr3[j]=99999999;          //line  12
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<arr3.length;i++)
    {
        if(arr3[i]!=99999999)
            System.out.print(arr3[i]+" ");
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that the question is about ArrayList. Also, I'm afraid this particular implementation leaves things to be desired. The value 99999999, which is used as a sentinel, might occur in the input. It would be better to use a dynamic structure, like `ArrayList`, to store the result of the union.

Comment: Please explain the code you've presented instead of just a code answer.

Comment: I am just giving a clue you have to put any garbage value

Comment: I'm glad to see you added an explanation. Unfortunately, the answer itself is still bad. There is no reason to use arrays. You should use a dynamic structure like ArrayList. If (for some reason) you must use arrays, you should consider using an array of `Integer` rather than `int`. Then you can use `null` instead of your "garbage value".  "Garbage values" or "sentinel values" are usually a bad idea, because  these values may still occur in the input.

Answer (score 0):

After testing, here is my best intersection approach.

Faster speed compared to pure HashSet Approach. HashSet and HashMap below has similar performance for arrays with more than 1 million records.

As for Java 8 Stream approach, speed is quite slow for array size larger then 10k.

Hope this can help.

```
public static List<String> hashMapIntersection(List<String> target, List<String> support) {
    List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String s : support) {
        map.put(s, 0);
    }
    for (String s : target) {
        if (map.containsKey(s)) {
            r.add(s);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
public static List<String> hashSetIntersection(List<String> a, List<String> b) {
    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(b);

    for (String s : a) {
        if (set.contains(s)) {
            r.add(s);
        }
    }
    print("intersection:" + r.size() + "-" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    return r;
}

public static void union(List<String> a, List<String> b) {
    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Set<String> r= new HashSet<String>(a);
    r.addAll(b);
    print("union:" + r.size() + "-" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods:

`CollectionUtils.containsAny` and `CollectionUtils.containsAll`

from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html).

Answer (score -1):

If you had your data in Sets you could use Guava's [`Sets`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) class.

Answer (score -1):

**Final solution:**

```
//all sorted items from both
public <T> List<T> getListReunion(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
    set.addAll(list1);
    set.addAll(list2);
    return new ArrayList<T>(set);
}

//common items from both
public <T> List<T> getListIntersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    list1.retainAll(list2);
    return list1;
}

//common items from list1 not present in list2
public <T> List<T> getListDifference(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    list1.removeAll(list2);
    return list1;
}
```

Comment: First method doesn't mutate, the next two do, feels inconsistent. What is the point in wrapping `list1.retainAll(list2);` in `getListIntersection`? it was already one line and it may hide that it is mutating the first list because it returns a list

Answer (score -1):

If the number matches  than I am checking it's occur first time or not with help of "indexOf()" if the number matches first time then print and save into in a string so, that when the next time same number matches then it's won't print because due to "indexOf()" condition will be false.

```
class Intersection
{
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  String s="";
    int[] array1 = {1, 2, 5, 5, 8, 9, 7,2,3512451,4,4,5 ,10};
    int[] array2 = {1, 0, 6, 15, 6, 5,4, 1,7, 0,5,4,5,2,3,8,5,3512451};


       for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++)
           {
               char c=(char)(array1[i]);
               if(array1[i] == (array2[j])&&s.indexOf(c)==-1)
               {    
                System.out.println("Common element is : "+(array1[i]));
                s+=c;
                }
           }
       }    
}
```

}

Comment: Don't just post code as an answer, give some little explanation of what are you doing

Comment: it's my first program which i uploaded

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.