# INTERSECT result of 2 ArrayList containing Integer values

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, intersection

I've two *ArrayList* both containing *Integer* values.  My objective is to get identical/common/duplicate values comparing these 2 list.  In other words (in SQL parlance), I need the [INTERSECT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersect_%28SQL%29) result of two lists, that is, values that appear in both list.

**Example:**

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list1.add(100);
list1.add(200);
list1.add(300);
list1.add(400);
list1.add(500);

ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(300);
list2.add(600);
```

One kind of implementation/solution I could think along is looping one of the list something like:

```
ArrayList<Integer> intersectList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (Integer intValue : list1) 
{
    if(list2.contains(intValue))
        intersectList.add(intValue);
}
```

In this case, `intersectList` would contain only 1 *Integer* item being added, that is `300`, which appears in both list.

My question is, are there any better/fastest/efficient way of implementing this logic?  Any options available in [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) library?. Any other ideas/suggestions/comments are appreciated.

**NOTE:** For illustration purpose, I've just shown here 5 items and 2 items being added into the list.  In my real-time implementation, there will be more than 1000 elements in each list.  Therefore, performance is also a *key factor* to be considered.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-union-of-arraylists-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're okay with overwriting result for list1:

`list1.retainAll(list2);`

otherwise clone/copy list1 first.

Not sure on performance though.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1.retainAll(list2)//for intersection
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ListUtils from org.apache.commons.collections if you do not want to modify existing list.

`ListUtils.intersection(list1, list2)`