# Comparing 2 lists and appending the differences into a 3rd

Tags: python, list, compare

I have an issue and I can't for the life of me get anything to return past ()

```
exam_solution = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C',\
           'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']

student_answers = ['B', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C',\
           'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']
```

I need to compare the 2 lists and append the differences into questions_missed = []
I haven't found anything remotely close to working. Any help would be appreciated

edit: In python been stroking out over it all day.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Also, what do you want questions_missed to look like? Like [true, true, false...]?

Comment: Python sorry, was in the process of having an episode

Comment: ## Your output should look like following:
##
##Congratulations!! You passed the exam
##You answered 17 questions correctly and 3 questions incorrectly
##The numbers of the questions you answered incorrectly are: 3 7 14 
##press enter to continue

Comment: I can not for the life of me find a good reference in my book or otherwise.

Comment: @user3029955: no, the question wasn't how you wanted to display the output, it was what format you wanted `questions_missed` in.  A list of booleans?  A list of the indices of the questions which were wrong?  Etc.

Comment: There is this similar question [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732312/differences-between-two-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

use python list comprehensions to check list diff:

```
print [(index, i, j) for index, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(exam_solution, student_answers)) if i != j]
[(2, 'A', 'B'), (6, 'B', 'A'), (13, 'A', 'B')]
```

Comment: added location in the list to the output

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this solution to fit your needs:

```
exam_solution = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']
student_answers = ['B', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']

results = []

correct = 0
incorrect = 0

index = 0
while index < len(student_answers):
    if student_answers[index] == exam_solution[index]:
        results.append(True)
        correct += 1
    else:
        results.append(False)
        incorrect += 1

    index += 1

print("You answered " + correct + " questions correctly and " + incorrect + " questions incorrectly.")
```

Comment: Much appreciated that gives me a great start point, thank you.

Comment: Iterating by explicitly incrementing an index is an antipattern in Python.  The loop is simply `results = [sol == ans for sol, ans in zip(exam_solution, student_answers)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehensions:

```
[x for i, x in enumerate(exam_solution) if exam_solution[i] != student_answers[i] ]
```

['A', 'B', 'A']

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an output in common English like this -

```
Question 3 A != B
Question 7 B != A
Question 14 A != B
```

You could try -

```
from array import *

exam_solution = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C',\
       'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']
student_answers = ['B', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C',\
       'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']
questions_missed = []
count = 0
for answer in exam_solution:
    if (answer != student_answers[count]):
            questions_missed.append(count)
    count = count + 1

for question in questions_missed:
    print str.format("Question {0} {1} != {2}", question+1,
            exam_solution[question], student_answers[question]);
```

Comment: Actually thanks a lot, that gave me an idea for part of the output I needed.  Very much appreciated this assignment was out of left field.

Answer (score 0):

Using the KISS design principle, that's how I'd do it:

```
exam_solution = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C',\
       'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']

student_answers = ['B', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C',\
       'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']

questions_missed = []

for index in range(len(exam_solution)):
    # this assumes exam_solution and student_answers have the same size!
    if exam_solution[index] != student_answers[index]:
        questions_missed.append(index)

print (questions_missed)
```

And the output is:

```
[2, 6, 13]
```

Comment: Actually that is near perfect, and it leaves it very open for me to add the rest of what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Actually the out put was supposed to be 3 7 14, odd

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(exam_solution, student_answers) if a != b]
print(L)
```

Mybe you can use [**zip**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function.

The output is:
`[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('A', 'B')]`

Answer (score 0):

Solution (use `set`):

```
>>> def result(solution, answers):
...     return set(str(n)+s for n, s in enumerate(solution)) - \ 
...            set(str(n)+r for n, r in enumerate(answers))
...
>>> result(exam_solution, student_answers)
... set(['6B', '13A', '2A'])
>>>
```

The result are wrong responses (you can convert to list `list(result(student_answers))`.