# Compare two arrays to get the missing array and new array in java

Tags: java

I have an array which shows the cities  selected  in database as cities=["1","3"] where 1 is Bombay and 3 is bangalore

Now while editing the user deselects Bombay and selects chennai, The new array is ["2","3"]

HTML:

```
<select name="cities">

<option value="1">Bombay</option>
<option value="2">Chennai</option>
<option value="3">Bangalore</option>
<option value="4">Delhi</option>
<option value="5">Calcutta</option>
</select>
```

How to get an array which contains the missing values(1)  and an array for newly  selected (2) so that when compared with selected array, if it is missing should update else should insert in  database

Comment: Like a set difference?

Comment: yes should the get missing in one array and newly selected in one array and later if missing array then should update in database else insert

Answer (score 3):

You can use guava libraries for getting the difference between the sets.
What you can do is convert bothe the arrays to Set

new HashSet(Arrays.asList(array));
And similalarly for the sencond array as well

Then pass the Sets to guava difference method

public static Sets.SetView [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732312/differences-between-two-arrays)(Set set1, Set set2)

.If you don't want to use any 3rd party libraries, You can check out this question
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  final String[] arr1 = {"1", "3"};
  final String[] arr2 = {"2", "3"};
  List<String> missing = new ArrayList<String>(); // the missing vals
  List<String> have = new ArrayList<String>();    // the common vals
  List<String> newV = new ArrayList<String>();    // the new entries

  Set<String> aSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arr1));
  Set<String> bSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arr2));

  for (String s : aSet) {
    if (bSet.contains(s)) {
      have.add(s);
    } else {
      missing.add(s);
    }
  }

  for (String s : bSet) {
    if (!aSet.contains(s)) {
      newV.add(s);
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: can you tell me only using list instead of set

Comment: kindly help me doing using list alone

Comment: Just replace `Set<String> aSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arr1));
` with `List<String> aSet = Arrays.asList(arr1);` but this won't weed out the duplicates.