# how can I implement the union and intersection of set theory with sets of objects

Tags: java, union, set

hi i've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-union-of-arraylists-in-java) how to implement the union and intersection when it you have two sets of data,that are strings.how can i do the same when my sets contain objects,and i want to get the union of only one property of each object?

Comment: "sets contain objects": `o`bjects or `O`bjects?

Comment: do you mean like using `retainAll` (intersection) or `addAll` (union)?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey yes exactly these two methods.But I want to override  them somehow so that it wont add an object if there's an object already in my set that has the same value in a selected property.If i'm not clear enough tell me so i can write an example.

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov you mean wheather my set contains Objects or my customs Objects? in that case i mean custom Objects

Comment: Any method you use you will need to override equals(). Just keep it in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I want to override them somehow so that it wont add an object if there's an object already in my set that has the same value in a selected property.If i'm not clear enough tell me so i can write an example.

I think the best way to do this is to use a ConcurrentMap.

```
ConcurrentMap<String, MyType> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

// the collection to retain.
for(MyType mt: retainedSet) map.put(mt.getKey(), mt);

// the collection to keep if not duplicated
for(MyType mt: onlyIfNewSet) map.putIfAbsent(mt.getKey(), mt);

// to get the intersection.
Set<String> toKeep = new HashSet<>();
for(MyType mt: onlyIfNewSet) toKeep.add(mt.getKey());

// keep only the keys which match.
map.keySet().retainAll(toKeep);
```

Comment: well it look okay,thanks but i'm sorry ican't figure out how's this works.I mean i guess MyType is my custom object,But how can i chose based on what field should the union and instersection should be done?

Comment: The "MyType" is your custom type and the "getKey()" is the field you want to key on.

Comment: Ok i've used your snippet it workd like a dream litteraly.Thank you for passing the knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Google Guava, has Sets class which contains these methods and many more.

Answer (score 0):

Intersection is using [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29), which uses equals. You should implement `equals()` method on the class that you want to do intersection.

I didn't find specific comments about `set.addAll()` implementation, but most probably it also uses `equals()` to determine if an object is already on the set.

If you want to compare only by a field, your equals() should only compare this field.

Comment: ok i figured it was somethiing like this,but you see i'm more interested right now on the union side.you're sure i should again override the equals()?

Comment: Java uses always equals() to see if to objects are equals, and addAll() specification says it performs union (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29). I don't see any reason to consider a different behavior

Answer (score 0):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-union-of-arraylists-in-java/5283079#5283079), use [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) methods `retainAll(Collection)`- intersection and `#addAll(Collection)`- union.

Since those methods use equals, you also have to override `equals` method in your Class and implement one-property based comparison.

In case it's simple comparison, here's an example (generated by my IDEA):

```
public class Main {

private Integer age;

...

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Main main = (Main) o;

    if (age != null ? !age.equals(main.age) : main.age != null) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: ok i had somehting like that in my mind but how can i  override equals() properly?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example. If you want dig in further about `equals`, [here is a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/760484).