# How to implement Jaccard index in Java or JSP?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, similarity

I have this problem in calculating Jaccard Similarity for finding similar books using transaction id from MySQL database of sales transactions :

t1= Java,Ruby,C

t2= Java,C#, Python

t3= C#, VB, C

....etc

Size of Java intersection = 2; (How could we find it out?)

Size of union = 3, (How could we find it out?)

Jaccard similarity = (intersection/union) = 2/3

But I don't understand how could I find out the "intersection" and "union" of the two vectors or how to implement it in Java/JSP.

Please help me and thanks a lot!

Comment: What does the data look like in the MySQL database?  What is the definition of union?  What is the definition of intersection?

Comment: Data in MySQL database is transaction id, books name and customer id/name. I want to find out the most bought books (intersection)in each transaction out of all the sales transaction (union).

Comment: Might be useful same approach using Arraylist - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-union-of-arraylists-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of standard [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) class. You can do an intersect, union and size calculation on sets.

Comment: Hi Konstantin, thanks a lot and I'm still quite confused about of how to use Set class. Therefore is there any example implementation that you might know of which will give me a clear picture.Thanks again!