# LinkedList with intersection and union

Tags: java, list, linked-list, intersection

I have two lists which both have integers added into. I want to intersect the two lists and union. I have my code, but for some reason it won't compile.

Any suggestions as to why I can't simply `LinkedList.intersection(argument, argument)`?

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Set;

public class IntegerSet 
{


    public static void main(String args[]) {


        LinkedList<Double> list1 = new LinkedList<Double>();
        list1.add((double) 5);
        list1.add((double) 15);
        list1.add((double) 3);
        list1.add((double) 15);


        LinkedList<Double> list2 = new LinkedList<Double>();
        list2.add((double) 15);
        list2.add((double) 8);
        list2.add((double) 16);
        list2.add((double) 11);

        // Calculating Intersection of two Set in Java
        LinkedList<Double> intersection = LinkedList.intersection(list1, list2);
        System.out.printf("Intersection of two Set %s and %s in Java is %s %n",
                list1.toString(), list2.toString(), intersection.toString());
        System.err.println("Number of elements common in two Set : "
                           + intersection.size());

        // Calculating Union of two Set in Java
        LinkedList<Double> union = LinkedList.union(list1, list2);
        System.out.printf("Union of two Set %s and %s in Java is %s %n",
                list1.toString(), list2.toString(), union.toString());
        System.out.println("total number of element in union of two Set is : "
                            + union.size());
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, there's no `intersection` method in the `LinkedList` class.  You might want to look at the Javadoc at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Where did you see such method? If it's in a 3-rd party lib (jar) you need to import it.

Comment: ... and you do not need to cast your numeric literals into `double`.

Comment: Seems ironic that you named your class "IntegerSet" but you are using a List of Doubles...

Comment: Double is for redundancy as I'm designing for double in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact that trying to use `intersection` and `union` methods on a `linked list` is one of the most awful things you can do in terms of complexity.  Also,

```
// Calculating Union of two Set in Java
LinkedList<Double> union = LinkedList.union(list1, list2);
```

A `Set` is not the same as a `List`.  Further this exists in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html):

```
col.retainAll(otherCol) // for intersection
col.addAll(otherCol) // for union
```

Also see this post: [Intersection and union of ArrayLists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5283079/205426)

Third party library:  [Apache Commons CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html)

Comment: Thanks but the problem with this is that it will print: For intersection: [15.0, 15.0]
For union: [15.0, 8.0, 16.0, 11.0, 15.0, 15.0] It should print only one 15.0 for the union instead of each from own list...

Comment: Oh totally forgot about removeAll then addAll.

Comment: @user2924294 As an addition. Check out the "**Set Interface Bulk Operations**" section from the Oracle's official [Java Tutorials. Trail: Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) (scroll down on that page). It covers intersection, union and also difference.