# compare 2 lists in java

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I am getting data from the two different databases and storing them in the java.util.List

```
Elements of database:1 
column 1                   column 2
**Investment Number**     Investment Name
123                         abcwe
124                         agsdf
454                         lkjcv
784                         ojncv
478                         hfdgh
852                         qweyu
745                         mmkty
201                         pbckl
560                         jklfg
741                         nbvbn
```

storing them in list1

Elements of database:2

```
column 1                   column 2
Investment Number     Property Number
123                         548
980                         743
454                         200
350                         357
478                         698
852                         223
745                         795
784                         213
341                         022
741                         900
```

storing them in list2

need to compare according to the Investment Numbers if Investment Number of list1 available in list2 then need to keep and discard others.

Thanks,

Comment: Loop through both lists and do a comparison...?

Comment: Hi Mohammad there is huge amount of data in both lists around 5 lac in one list it may reduce the performance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intersection and union of ArrayLists in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java)

Comment: 500,000 (I'm assuming that's what 5 lac is, according to Wikipedia) entries in one list? I'm curious: why not try and do this in the database?

Comment: I don't really think List is the best way to store your data. That, of course, depends on later usage. And I don't phantom how you store 2 values as a list element. I would suggest using Map, it consist of a unique identifier (investment number) and a value, and has a method to check if an identifier is in the map.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have already filtered out as much as possible both lists are coming from saperate databases

Comment: @WrongASP You use an object type (I hope); also, I assume you mean fathom (or it's very [ghostly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Phantom)).

Comment: @PrashantBhagwani: Ok, so they're in different databases (not just different database tables). And just to clarify what you're trying to do, you've got your List1 and List2. You're scanning through List1 and checking to see if there is a matching Investment Number in List2. If there's not, then you're removing that element from List1 (or if there is a match, you're adding that element to List3, which contains the matches). Correct?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch: I meant fathom. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two list, you can do the following:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 5, 6, 7));
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
list1.retainAll(list2);
System.out.println("list1 = " + list1);
```

And the result will be:

```
list1 = [5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: is this work also in 2 List<EntityModel> ??

Answer (score 2):

Create a wrapper class for your two classes and use List.retainAll().
Here is some code

You already have classes that are the equivalents of Blam and Hoot;
they are included for completeness

```
public class Blam
{
    private String investmentNumber;
    private String investmentName;

    ... getters and setters
}

public class Hoot
{
    private String investmentNumber;
    private String propertyNumber;

    ... getters and setters
}

public class Wrapper
{
    private Blam blam;
    private Hoot hoot;

    public Wrapper(final Blam blam)
    {
        this.blam = blam;
    }

    public Wrapper(final Hoot hoot)
    {
        this.hoot = hoot;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object oThat)
    {
        if (this == oThat)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (oThat instanceof Wrapper)
        {
            Wrapper wThat = (Wrapper)oThat;
            String myInvestmentNumber;
            String yourInvestmentNumber;

            if (blam != null)
            {
                myInvestmentNumber = blam.getInvestmentNumber();
            }
            else
            {
                myInvestmentNumber = hoot.getInvestmentNumber();
            }

            if (wThat.blam != null)
            {
                yourInvestmentNumber = wThat.blam.getInvestmentNumber();
            }
            else
            {
                yourInvestmentNumber = wThat.hoot.getInvestmentNumber();
            }

            return StringUtils.equals(myInvestmentNumber, yourInvestmentNumber);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode()
    {
        ... implement this using blam and hoot as in equals() above.
    }

            ... getters for Hoot and Blam values as needed.
}


    List<Wrapper> listOne = new ArrayList<Wrapper>();
    List<Wrapper> listTwo = new ArrayList<Wrapper>();

    ... populate listOne with wrapped Blam values.
    ... populate listTwo with wrapped Hoot values.

    listTwo.retainAll(listOne);
```

After executing the retainAll, the Hoot list contains all the values from database 2 for which there was a corresponding entry in database 1.

Note: StringUtils is an apache commons lang class that performs a null safe equals (and other stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two pojos corresponding to two different table of two different datbase

Pojo1-------entity class corressponding to first table of first database

Pojo2-------entity class corressponding to second table of second database

```
 List<Pojo1> listOne = new ArrayList<Pojo1>();
  List<Pojo2> listTwo = new ArrayList<Pojo2>();
   listTwo.retainAll(listOne);
```

Note that in these two pojos you have to override hashcode() and equals() method of Object class, because in retainAll, you are comparing the objects of two pojos