# How to copy only new items from one list to another

Tags: java, android

I have a List of String L1

I have another List of String L2

I want to copy only those items from L1 to L2 which are not already contained in L2

I know it might be quite easy but I could not find an easy solution

Comment: Are the values in the List always unique? If yes, using a Set would be more appropriate.

Comment: This question seems as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java.

Comment: You could remove the existing elements from the new list using removeAll and passing it the existing list, now the new list only contains the new items, you can now call addAll on the existing list passing it the new list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take help form the below snippet. This will help.

```
        List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        l1.add("A");
        l1.add("B");
        l1.add("C");

        l2.add("C");
        l2.add("D");
        l2.add("E");

        Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
        s.addAll(l1);
        s.addAll(l2);

        List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
        finalList.addAll(s);

        for (String str : finalList) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

fill a set with the two lists, then convert the set back into a list (list2).

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list2);
set.addAll(list1);
list2 = new ArrayList(set);
```

Comment: @RahulVerma added 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1","2","3"}));
stringSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1","2","3","4"}));
List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>(stringSet);
```