# Porting from Python to Java: looking for a fast implementation of an array search operation

Tags: java, python, arrays, list, arraylist

I am porting some Python code into Java and need to find an efficient implementation of the following Python operation:

```
sum([x in lstLong for x in lstShort])
```

where `lstLong` and `lstShort` are string lists. So here I am counting how many elements from `lstShort` appear in `lstLong`. In the Java implementation, both of these are `String[]`. What's the fastest way of counting this sum?

A more general question is whether there are any generic guidelines for writing "fast equivalents" in Java of Python list comprehension operations like the one above. I am mostly interested in arrays/lists of `String`s, in case it makes the answer easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intersection and union of ArrayLists in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java). Just find the length of the intersection.

Comment: Even in Python, this isn't a good way to do the counting. It takes quadratic time, when something like `len(set(lstShort).intersection(lstLong))` takes average-case linear time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert both to `ArrayList<String>`, you can use

```
lstLong.retainAll(lstShort).size();
```

You can do the conversion with

```
new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(var));
```