# Compare two array lists in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have two different arrays oldUsers and newUsers containing instances of the class User. User contain firstname, lastname and age attributes. I want to know the number of oldUsers objects in the newUsers array that have the same attributes. Shall I use two for loops and compare the arrays one per one or is there a function that can do the same work ?

Comment: First, override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in the `User` class.

Comment: Yes, you can use two for loops. I'm not sure about a function that already exists. If using two for loops works "good enough" use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()`. Then you can implement an `intersection()` method.

```
Number of identical values: 2
------------------------------
- { 'firstname': 'Bob', 'lastname': 'Smith', 'age': 30 }
- { 'firstname': 'Robert', 'lastname': 'Brown', 'age': 51 }
```

#### Main

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> oldUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
        List<User> newUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
        List<User> intersect;

        oldUsers.addAll(Arrays.asList(
            new User("Bob", "Smith", 30),
            new User("Tom", "Jones", 42),
            new User("Robert", "Brown", 51),
            new User("James", "Jones", 28)
        ));

        newUsers.addAll(Arrays.asList(
            new User("Robert", "Brown", 51), // Same
            new User("Bob", "Smith", 30),    // Same
            new User("Tom", "Jones", 21),
            new User("James", "Hendrix", 28)
        ));

        intersect = intersection(oldUsers, newUsers);

        System.out.printf("Number of identical values: %d%n%s%n",
                intersect.size(), "------------------------------");
        for (User user : intersect) {
            System.out.printf("- %s%n", user);
        }
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/5283123/1762224
    public static <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T t : list1) {
            if (list2.contains(t)) {
                list.add(t);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

#### User

```
public class User {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int age;

    public String getFirstname() { return firstname; }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) { this.firstname = firstname; }

    public String getLastname() { return lastname; }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) { this.lastname = lastname; }

    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }

    public User(String firstname, String lastname, int age) {
        super();
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + age;
        result = prime * result + ((firstname == null) ? 0 : firstname.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((lastname == null) ? 0 : lastname.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

        User other = (User) obj;

        if (age != other.age) return false;

        if (firstname == null) {
            if (other.firstname != null) return false;
        } else if (!firstname.equals(other.firstname)) return false;

        if (lastname == null) {
            if (other.lastname != null) return false;
        } else if (!lastname.equals(other.lastname)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{ 'firstname': '%s', 'lastname': '%s', 'age': %d }",
                firstname, lastname, age);
    }
}
```

---

## Alternative Methods

#### Set :: Retain All

```
public static <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>(list1);
    set.retainAll(new HashSet<T>(list2));
    return new ArrayList<T>(set);
}
```

#### List :: Java 8 Filter Stream

```
public static <T> List<T> intersection(Collection<T> list1, Collection<T> list2) {
    return list1.stream().filter(item -> list2.contains(item)).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me what is the  final int prime = 31; ? I don't get it.

Comment: @user3235881 It is the default value for a prime multiplier provided by Eclipse IDE. For the reasoning behind this, check out: [***Why does Java's hashCode() in String use 31 as a multiplier?***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier).

Comment: @user3235881 In my example above, you will always get 2 in the console, unless you changed something. There is nothing wrong with the equals. It is using `String.equals()` which compares names lexicographically.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `User` objects correctly implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`, I would use one of the lists' `retainAll(Collection other)` method to craft the intersection of both lists and then return its size.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `equals()` and `hashCode()` implemented correctly, you can place all inputs from `oldUsers` array to `Set` and then check data from `newUsers` if they are in that `Set` or not. This will work in `O(max(n, m))` (place data in `Set` is `O(n)`, check `newUsers` if they are in Set is  `O(m)`, so you have `O(n) + O(m) = O(max(n,m))`, where `n` is size of `oldUsers` list and `m` is size of `newUsers` list).

For example:

```
    private int numberOfSameUsers(ArrayList<User> oldUsers, ArrayList<User> newUsers) {
        Set<User> oldUsersSet = new HashSet<>(oldUsers);
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < newUsers.size(); i++) if (oldUsersSet.contains(newUsers.get(i))) counter++;
        return counter;
    }
```