# How to compare two list of different size and return common records from both the list...in java

Tags: java

This is the code.How to compare two list of different size and return common records from both the list...in java

```
for (Bean1 obj1 : list1) {
    for (Bean2 obj2 : list2) {
        if (obj1.getNum1().equals(obj2.getNum2())) {
        }
        else {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java

Comment: And what objects do you want in the result? The ones from the first list or the ones from the second list?

Answer (score 0):

You can save them into a new list whose generics is super class of `Bean1`and `Bean2` , say `Object`.

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (Bean1 obj1 : list1) {
for (Bean2 obj2 : list2) {
    if (obj1.getNum1().equals(obj2.getNum2())) {
            list .add(obj1);
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Will that matter ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Bean1 and Bean2 contains num1 and num2 of type String, please try below example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Bean1> list1 = new ArrayList<Bean1>();
    List<Bean2> list2 = new ArrayList<Bean2>();
    List<Object> list3 = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Bean1 bean1 = new Bean1();
    Bean1 bean11 = new Bean1();
    Bean1 bean12 = new Bean1();

    Bean2 bean2 = new Bean2();
    Bean2 bean21 = new Bean2();
    Bean2 bean22 = new Bean2();
    Bean2 bean23 = new Bean2();

    bean1.setNum1("a");
    list1.add(bean1);
    bean11.setNum1("b");
    list1.add(bean11);
    bean12.setNum1("c");
    list1.add(bean12);

    bean2.setNum2("a");
    list2.add(bean2);
    bean21.setNum2("d");
    list2.add(bean21);
    bean22.setNum2("e");
    list2.add(bean22);
    bean23.setNum2("b");
    list2.add(bean23);

    for (Bean1 ben1 : list1) {
        for (Bean2 ben2 : list2) {
            if (ben1.getNum1().equals(ben2.getNum2())) {
                list3.add(ben1.getNum1());
            }
        }
    }

    for (Object obj : list3) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is reason in `if-else` statement? In both cases you have `list1.size() * list2.size()` iterations

Comment: @Ilya : Corrected the code. Was trying something else previously.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in `list1.size() + list2.size()` iterations instead of `list1.size() * list2.size()`

```
  List intersection = new ArrayList(Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size()));
  Set num2s = new HashSet();
  for (Bean2 bean2 : list2)
  {
     num2s.add(bean2.getName2());
  }

  for (Iterator<Bean1> iter = list1.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) 
  {
     Bean1 bean1 = iter.next();
     if (num2s.contains(bean1.getName1())) 
     {
         intersection.add(bean1);
     }
  }
  // return intersection;
```