# Intersection between two arraylist Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I wanted to find an intersection between two arraylist that are of byte[] format and return the common indices. I have the code as follows and it works correctly:

```
ArrayList<Integer> intersect = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int j = 0; j < A.size(); j++)
    {
        byte [] t = A.get(j); 
        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < B.size(); j1++)
        {
            byte[] t1 = B.get(j1);
            if (Arrays.equals(t, t1))
            {
                intersect.add(j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, as you can see, I have to use two for loops. Is there any way I can do it without using any for loops? I have tried to use **"retainAll"** but for some reason, it kept giving me an empty array. What can be the possible reason for that?

Comment: _I have tried to use "retainAll" but for some reason, it kept giving me an empty array. What can be the possible reason for that?_ Because the implementation of `equals()` for arrays checks for identity, not contents.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java might provide some useful information using other collection types to get the same behavior.

Comment: @Shahnewaz Given that you need control over the equality check, the code you are using is probably the best you can do without another data structure. Also, given that you are trying to "retain" the position of the array in the list (and not the array itself), `retainsAll()` would never have given you the result you were looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intersection and union of ArrayLists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java)

Comment: @Chisko eh... not _really_. The concept is the same, but the accepted answer is not going to work.

Comment: @SeanBright what about any of the other 5-10 answers?

Comment: @Chisko I'm not sure. Do any of them call `Arrays.equals()?` If not, then I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just dont want to use for loops, you may try the Java 8 streams, since you have not shared the complete code I did not try it out.

```
List<T> intersect = list1.stream()
.filter(list2::contains)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: So, for my list it should be
    List<T> intersect = A.stream().filter(B::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
Right?

Comment: @SeanBright Why on earth it ***should*** work for `<T> = Array `if the OP is not even asking for that?!!!

Comment: @SeanBright You are right... OP's question is very bad!

Answer (score 0):

I think for `T` your solution with brutforce is not so bad. This is a small refactoring of it. Yes, for specific `T` (e.g. `int`) you could use special structures, but in general case, I think this is not implementable.

```
public static <T> List<Integer> intersect(List<T> A, List<T> B, BiPredicate<T, T> isEqual) {
    List<Integer> intersect = new LinkedList<>();
    int i = -1;

    for (T a : A) {
        i++;

        if (B.stream().anyMatch(b -> isEqual.test(a, b)))
            intersect.add(i);
    }

    return intersect;
}
```

Client code could look like:

```
List<byte[]> a = Collections.emptyList();
List<byte[]> b = Collections.emptyList();
List<Integer> intersect = intersect(a, b, Arrays::equals);
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help:

```
public <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (T t : list1) {
            if(list2.contains(t)) {
                list.add(t);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Reference:
[Intersection and union of ArrayLists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java)

Comment: you sneaky punk ;)