# how to loop through 2 array lists and return the number of items matched and the matched items in firestore?

Tags: java, android, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

I have an `ArrayList` where I store array of items of a specific field of a document, and I am sending it to another activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ProgramToProgram.this, com.example.newapp.ProgramToProgram1.class);
intent.putExtra("fids", arrayList1);
startActivity(intent);
```

I recieve it in the other activity like this:

```
arraylist3 = (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("fids");
```

Now I have another array list in this activty where I am storing another set of items:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        pid = docIds.get(position);

        fgboys1.whereEqualTo("pid", pid)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            String fid = documentSnapshot.get("fid").toString();
                            arrayList1.add(fid);
                            arrayAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(ProgramToProgram1.this, "FIND OUT REGISTERED OR NOT REGISTERED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
});
```

Now I want to compare the items of arraylist3 and arraylist1 and return the number of items and the similar items. How do I do it?

This is what I have tried, but the app crashes each time:

```
registered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i;

        arraylist3 = (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("fids");

        for (i = 0; i <arraylist3.size(); i++) {
            if (arraylist3.contains(arrayList1.get(i))) {
                i++;
            }
        }
        tv_reg.setText(i);
    }
});
```

this is the error shown in log :

```
  2020-02-12 11:50:19.014 16489-16489/com.example.newapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.newapp, PID: 16489
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:338)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5494)
    at com.example.newapp.ProgramToProgram1$4.onClick(ProgramToProgram1.java:215)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java

Comment: please reformat this

Comment: If your application is crashing, a good place to start is usually by looking at the crash log. Please attach it here if you need help deciphering it.

Comment: i have shown the error

Answer (score 1):

There are some clear bugs in this code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i;

    arraylist3 = (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("fids");

    for (i = 0; i <arraylist3.size(); i++) {
        if (arraylist3.contains(arrayList1.get(i))) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    tv_reg.setText(i);
}
```

Problem #1: you are using `i` for two (conflicting) purposes: as a counter, and as a loop variable.  That won't work.

Problem #2: you are appear to be using the wrong `arrayList` size in:

```
for (i = 0; i <arraylist3.size(); i++) {
```

versus

```
arrayList1.get(i)
```

If the two lists are not guaranteed to always have the same size, that is liable to either skip counting some elements, or give an index out of bounds exception (when `i >= arrayList1.size()`).

---

There are also some design problems;

- Your variable names are uninformative: `arrayList1` and `arrayList3` say nothing about the meaning of the lists
- The `arrayList3` variable looks like it could / should be a local variable not a field.

Comment: problem #1 i understood, i'll just make it -                                                           
    public void onClick(View v) {
    int i,r;
    Arraylist<String> arraylist3 = new Arraylist<>();
    arraylist3 = (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("fids");

    for (i = 0; i <arraylist3.size(); i++) {
        if (arraylist3.contains(arrayList1.get(r))) {
            r++;
        }
    }
    tv_reg.setText(r);
}

Comment: problem #2 , then what do i do??

Comment: arraylist1 and arraylist3 both take in array of strings from firestore

Comment: If you want to iterate through the values of `arrayList1`, use `arrayList1.size()` of course.

Comment: And please use **meaningful** variable names.

Comment: Or you could write `for (String s: arrayList1) { if (arrayList3.contains(s)) {count++;}}`.  This is all pretty basic stuff ... Java 101 really.

Comment: how do i return the items that are matching? the elements stored in both the array lists's are string value's and they are queried from firestore

Comment: Well ... I guess you just format them as text and put them in the text box.  Your code is not "returning" anything.  It is a `onClick` button.