# Intersection of two List in JAVA

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, stream

I am trying to get the intersection between Two List in JAVA, Please find the List below

LIST 1:

```java
List<EligViewEventSubject> list1=  new ArrayList<>();

list1=   [EligViewEventSubject [event=EOD, subjectTypeCd=HOLDINGS, region=IA], EligViewEventSubject [event=EOD, subjectTypeCd=ASSETS, region=IA]]
```

LIST 2:

```java
List<EligViewEventSubject> list2=  new ArrayList<>();

list2 = [EligViewEventSubject [event=EOD, subjectTypeCd=ASSETS, region=IA]]
```

The Result for the above should be Like below

```java
List<EligViewEventSubject> resultList =  new ArrayList<>();

resultList = [EligViewEventSubject [event=EOD, subjectTypeCd=ASSETS, region=IA]]
```

In short i want the Matching ones alone(intersection)

I have tried the below:

```java
List<EligViewEventSubject> unionList = new ArrayList<>(list1);
        unionList.addAll(list2);

List<EligViewEventSubject> intersectionList = new ArrayList<>(list1);
        intersectionList.retainAll(list2);
```

Union List I get as:

```java
[EligViewEventSubject [event=EOD, subjectTypeCd=HOLDINGS, region=IA], EligViewEventSubject [event=EOD, subjectTypeCd=ASSETS, region=IA], EligViewEventSubject [event=EOD, subjectTypeCd=ASSETS, region=IA]]
```

Intersection  is `[]`

Please share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference this question, as this has already been answered. [Intersection and union of ArrayLists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java)

To summarize, you can get the intersection of two arraylists in java as such:

```
public <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(); 

    for (T t : list1){
       if(list2.contains(t)){
           list.add(t); 
       } 
    } 

   return list; 
}
```

Comment: it again return an empty list

Comment: @KiranSureshraaj set breakpoints on list.add(t) and if(list2.contains(t)). See why the list doesn't contain the item.

Comment: @KiranSureshraaj also, please copy your full code here (in a code block, so it gets formatted as code instead of text)