# How do I use removeAll when comparing 2 Arraylist<String[]>?

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to compare two `ArrayList<String[]>` and get differences between them, so I thought using `.removeAll` as in `ArrayList<String>` but I don't know how to use it with `ArrayList<String[]>`. As example below:

```
        ArrayList<String[]> a = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        ArrayList<String[]> b = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        a.add(new String[] {"1","1"});
        a.add(new String[] {"2","2"});
        a.add(new String[] {"3","3"});
        a.add(new String[] {"4","4"});
        b.add(new String[] {"1","1"});
        b.add(new String[] {"2","2"});
        b.add(new String[] {"3","4"}); // I'd like to compare both and remove **a** to get only this line!
        b.add(new String[] {"4","4"});
```

I'd like an ouput as below:

```
[3,4]
```

Any tip how to get just this line?

Comment: How is this question different to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java ?

Comment: @jschnasse I think because OP is working with `String[]` which don't have an overriden `equals()` nor `hashCode()` method. Which are used for the `removeAll()`, `containsAll()` and `retainAll()` method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intersection and union of ArrayLists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `String[]` in a class implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()`. For extra benefit, also implement `toString()`, so it's easy to print.

```java
public final class StringArray {
    private final String[] arr;
    public StringArray(String... arr) {
        this.arr = arr.clone();
    }
    public String get(int index) {
        return this.arr[index];
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(this.arr);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (! (obj instanceof StringArray))
            return false;
        StringArray that = (StringArray) obj;
        return Arrays.equals(this.arr, that.arr);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(this.arr);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
ArrayList<StringArray> a = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<StringArray> b = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(new StringArray("1","1"));
a.add(new StringArray("2","2"));
a.add(new StringArray("3","3"));
a.add(new StringArray("4","4"));
b.add(new StringArray("1","1"));
b.add(new StringArray("2","2"));
b.add(new StringArray("3","4"));
b.add(new StringArray("4","4"));

b.removeAll(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

*Output*

```
[[3, 4]]
```

If you had tried printing a `List<String[]>`, it would have shown something like `[[Ljava.lang.String;@5ca881b5]`, not showing the string values at all.

Comment: Thank you! It worked as I expected. I made few changes in my project and now it is working great. :)

Answer (score 1):

`removeAll` uses `equals` of the content objects. If you want to compare 2 arrays (`String[]`) based on their content and not their identity, you need to use `Arrays.equals()`.

Now we can remove some content form the list conditionally:

```
b.removeIf(bStrings -> {
    for (String[] aStrings : a) {
        if (Arrays.equals(aStrings, bStrings))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
})
```

However there is also another solution:

---

To make `removeAll` work, you need to convert the content to something, that can be compared for structural equality, so the natural conversion from a `String[]` to retain the order would be to make it a `List`.

```java
final List<List<String>> a2 = a.stream().map(Arrays::asList).collect(Collectors.toList());
final List<List<String>> b2 = b.stream().map(Arrays::asList).collect(Collectors.toList());
// asymmetric difference
b2.removeAll(a2);
System.out.println(b2);

// if you really need the inner type to be String[]
final List<String[]> b3 = b2.stream()
                            .map(strings -> strings.toArray(String[]::new))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(b3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get `replaceAll` to work in an intuitive fashion with an `ArrayList<String[]>`:

- The `List<T>` API specifies that `replaceAll` shall use `T.equals`.
- The `equals` method for array types returns `true` if and only if the target and the argument object are the same object.

Solutions:

If you want to use `removeAll` in this, you need to use a different element type for the `List`.  Depending on the situation, you could make the element a `List` or `Set` type, a generic `Pair` type or a custom class.  The basic requirement is that the type provides an `equals` method that compares "by value".

The other alternatives for computing the list difference *include* using a simple nested loop with an iterator to do the removal or using `removeIf` as per @Hawk's answer.

---

All of the above will be `O(MN)` where `M` and `N` are the respective list lengths.

If the lists you are comparing are likely to be large, you could create a temporary set so that you can get `O(MlogN)` or `O(M) + O(N)` time complexity; e.g.

```
    Set<...> temp = new HashSet<>(a);  // This step is O(M)
    b.removeAll(temp);                 // This step is O(N)
```

Note that you need to factor in the cost of creating the temporary set, AND the space overhead.

---

Finally, there is a tricky issue of what to do if either of the lists contain multiple instances of a given pair.  Are duplicates possible?  If not, it may be better (simpler, more performant) to use a `Set` class to represent `a` and `b`.

Comment: Thanks for replying... nice information. BTW, duplicated isn't possible in my array.

Comment: So would it be better to represent them as `Set` instances?  The way that you are "differencing" them won't notice differences in element order, so I surmise that is not significant.