# Union of N lists in java

Tags: java, collections

What is the best way to create a union of N lists in java ?

For eg

```
List<Integer> LIST_1 = Lists.newArrayList(1);

List<Integer> LIST_2 = Lists.newArrayList(2);

List<Integer> LIST_3 = Lists.newArrayList(3);

List<Integer> LIST_4 = Lists.newArrayList(4);

List<Integer> LIST_1_2_3_4 = Lists.newArrayList(1,2,3,4);

assert LIST_1_2_3_4.equals(union(LIST_1,LIST_2,LIST_3,LIST_4)); 

The union method will take a var args parameter

<Item> List<Item> union(List<Item> ... itemLists)
```

Is there a library which provides this method.Simplest way is to loop through the array and accumulate each list into one

Comment: apache collections : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html#union(java.util.List, java.util.List)

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths This seems to work on 2 lists only...

Comment: or guava : http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
List<Integer> joined = new ArrayList<>( Iterables.concat(LIST_1, LIST_2, LIST_3, LIST_4) );
```

or for comparison only:

```
Iterables.elementsEqual( LIST_1_2_3_4, Iterables.concat(LIST_1, LIST_2, LIST_3, LIST_4) );
```

Comment: `Iterables.concat` returns an `Iterable`. I didn't find an ArrayList constructor which takes an `Iterable` as input. Instead, I used Guava's `Lists` like so: `Lists.newArrayList( Iterables.concat(LIST_1, LIST_2, LIST_3, LIST_4) );`

Answer (score 6):

There may be a library, but including it only for these 3 lines of code would probably not worth another dependency...

```
private static <Item> List<Item> union(List<Item> ... itemLists)
{
    List<Item> result = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for (List<Item> list : itemLists) result.addAll(list);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should use a Set to avoid duplicated elements and then return a list containing the elements that are in the set you buit.

Comment: To avoid increasing the size of the internal array in the result list, i would calculate the total size of the result list and then create it with the total size. Just loop through the itemLists, sum their size and pass it as in argumento for the result ArrayList contructor

Comment: @ZouZou that, however wouldn't be a true union of the lists, since each list itself could already contain duplicates.

Comment: @ZouZou This was not part of the question. Maybe the elements *should* occur as often as they occur in the list? If there should be no duplicates, you're right, of course.

Comment: @Thomas I was thinking of a more mathematical way, i.e the lists you pass as parameters does not contain duplicated elements. If it's not the case, then yes this answer has the right approach.

Comment: @Marco13 thanks for the quick response.I did implement the method in the way you did.I was wondering if there was already a library present I would use that rather than make my own.Apache Common Collections and Guava have methods but they are only for 2 lists

Comment: @AbhijeetKushe no, Guava provides methods for multiple iterables (e.g. lists)

Comment: @Thomas I liked the solution which you gave below.Will stick with that for now

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by best solution but a simple solution would involve using the `addAll` method.

For extra performance you may also hint the size by summing all sizes.

`new ArrayList<...>(totalSizeHere)`

Also see this answer: [How to do union, intersect, difference and reverse data in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590677/how-to-union-intersect-difference-and-reverse-data-in-java)