# Concatenating multiple ArrayLists

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

Is there a method to concatenate multiple `ArrayLists`?

ex:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a
ArrayList<Integer> b
ArrayList<Integer> c

ArrayList<Integer> d = a + b + c
```

where d is a single `ArrayList<Integer>` that contains all of the values of a,b,c in their preserved orders

Comment: I had asked  a similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230853/union-of-n-lists-in-java

Answer (score 6):

Use [`addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method

```
d.addAll(a);
d.addAll(b);
d.addAll(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is an unfortunate aspect of the collections framework that there is no built in list algebra, but things like Guava can provide methods that act like operators of the type you want.  Straight up java runtime library code would look like

```
List< Integer > d = new ArrayList<>( a );
d.addAll( b );
d.addAll( c );
```

Answer (score 2):

[addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method and an ArrayList constructor will do the trick. (There is no operator overriding in Java)

```
ArrayList<Integer> d = new ArrayList<Integer>(a);
d.addAll(b);
d.addAll(c);
```

Note that you can declare all your variables as [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) which is a better practice. That way you are stuck to ArrayList as a Collection implementation.

```
Collection<Integer> d = new ArrayList<Integer>(a);
```