# How to set array values automatically from another array's condition?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, function

Suppose I have array A :
    A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

And then I used a scanner to input my preferences to another array, suppose B, and then B has values :
    B = {1, 2, 6, 8, 9}

Now the question is, I have another array (C), is there a way so when array B is set then array C automatically has values :
    C = {3, 4, 5, 7}

Which C's values is the rest of A's that B doesn't pick. I'm using Java Language. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code how I have solve the same problem in python.

    `import numpy
    a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])  # declare array
    b = numpy.array([1,2,3])      # declare array 
    c = set(a) - set(b)`

Output:- c = [4,5]

Comment: oh right, I forgot to mention that my problem is with Java, do you know the function in Java, specifically netbeans?

Comment: Yes you can do it in same way in JAVA using `java.util.Set`. Set Class have methods like union, intersection. You can check this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Setoperationsunionintersectiondifferencesymmetricdifferenceissubsetissuperset.htm) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Set operations are standardised in Java using TreeSet.

```
Set<Integer> a = new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}));
Set<Integer> b = new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 6, 8, 9}));

//union
Set<Integer> c = new TreeSet<Integer>(a);
c.addAll(b);
System.out.println(c);

//intersection
Set<Integer> d = new TreeSet<Integer>(a);
d.retainAll(b);
System.out.println(d);

//difference
Set<Integer> e = new TreeSet<Integer>(a);
e.removeAll(b);
System.out.println(e);

//reverse
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(a);
java.util.Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590677/how-to-union-intersect-difference-and-reverse-data-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is quite simple. Suppose you have these arrays

```
private final int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
private int[] b; // I didn't set b to any value
private Integer[] c; // REMEMBER to set it yourself or you will have a null pointer
```

Now we create a method that sets `b`:

```
private void setB(int[] newB) {
    this.b = newB;
}
```

Now every time you set the value of B...

```
b = someMethodThatGetsUserInput();
```

You should NOT use the above, instead, you call:

```
setB(someMethodThatGetsUserInput());
```

Why? Because we'll write some code that changes C in `setB`. So every time you set the value of B, C is also changed.

Let's see how can we write the code to change C so that it is the elements that A has but B does not have.

The straightforward way is:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i : a) {
    if (!b.contains(a)) {
        list.add(i);
    }
}

c = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Easy!

There are other ways though, like using a set as others have mentioned. But I think you, as a beginner, should learn the most straightforward and a little inefficient way first.

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil