# String matching within nested for loop

Tags: java

Lets say i have two different Strings of given pojo type.

```
 List 1 = "one", "two", "three", "four", "five".
 List 2 = "one", "two", "four", "five".
```

I wants to retrieve a string that doesn't found in another list and add it into another list(say List 3).
how can i do this?

i'm trying this:-

```
 for ( SettlementReportNB showSellementReport : settlementReportList )
        {
            String merchantreferencenumber = showSellementReport.getMerchantreferencenumber();
            for ( AllTransactions showAllTransaction : allTransactionsList )
            {
                String merchantTxnId = showAllTransaction.getMerchantTxnId();
                if ( !merchantreferencenumber.equals( merchantTxnId ) )
                {
                    idNotFound.add( merchantTxnId );
                }
            }
        }
```

but it is not giving me an expected answer.

- Answer should be "three" because it is not present in another list.

Comment: what is your expected result and what are you getting right now

Comment: Answer should be "three"

Comment: The answer here exposes a simple way of doing set operations on lists http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590677/how-to-do-union-intersect-difference-and-reverse-data-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the string to result too soon. Your code has to wait for the loop to finish before calling `idNotFound.add();`

Define a `boolean` variable `notFound`, and set it to `true` before the loop. If you find a match in the loop, set the variable to `false`, and break out of the loop.

If the variable remains `true` after the loop is over, call `idNotFound.add();`

Answer (score 1):

Or you could something like this:

```
List list1 = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
List list2 = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "four", "five");

//create a clone of list1
List list3 = new ArrayList<>(list1);

//remove all elements of list2 from list1
list3.removeAll(list2);

//output : [three]
System.out.print(list3);
```

You will end up wit list3 that has only [three]

Or try something like this to keep your existing code :

```
for ( SettlementReportNB showSellementReport : settlementReportList ) {

    String allTransactionsList = showSellementReport.getMerchantreferencenumber();

    if ( isNotContain(allTransactionsList, allTransactionsList))
    {
        idNotFound.add( merchantTxnId );
    }

}

private boolean isNotContain(List allTransactionsList, String merchantreferencenumber) {

    for ( AllTransactions showAllTransaction : allTransactionsList )
    {
        String merchantTxnId = showAllTransaction.getMerchantTxnId();
        if ( merchantreferencenumber.equals( merchantTxnId ) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: what if user wants the original list1 contents?

Comment: easy check the post again (create a new copy of list1)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to verify all the elements that are not present in the second list only, just create a Set and use the !contains from the first list, if you need to verify both lists then add the second for from the example below:

```
Set<String> list3 = new HashSet<String>();
for (String text : list1) {
  if (!list2.contains(text)) list3.add(text);
}
for (String text : list2) {
  if (!list1.contains(text)) list3.add(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second for loop does not check *every* element. It checks only if one element does not match the compared `String`. You have to iterate over the whole list before you are sure it's not already present e.g.

```
for (SettlementReportNB showSellementReport: settlementReportList) {

    boolean notPresent = false;
    String merchantTxnId = null;
    String merchantreferencenumber = showSellementReport.getMerchantreferencenumber();
    for (AllTransactions showAllTransaction: allTransactionsList) {
        merchantTxnId = showAllTransaction.getMerchantTxnId();
        if (merchantreferencenumber.equals(merchantTxnId)) {
            notPresent = false;
            break; // get out of loop because it already exists
        } else {
            notPresent = true;
        }
    }
    if (notPresent) idNotFound.add(merchantTxnId);
}
```

Or you could use any of the other answers with List.util functions

Answer (score 0):

May be this case

```
        List<String> a1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"));
        List<String> a2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( "one", "two", "four", "five"));

        Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<>(a1);
        Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<>(a2);

        s2.removeAll(s1);

        List<String> a3 = new ArrayList<>(s2);

        List<String> result =  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( "six"));
        result.addAll(a3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 then use *Lambdas* - it will be much faster and will save you a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
List a = new ArrayList(asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five"));
List b = new ArrayList(asList("one", "two", "four", "five"));
List c = new ArrayList();
c.addAll(a);
c.addAll(b);
c.removeIf(o -> a.contains(o) && b.contains(o));
```