# How to compare two arrays in java and return an element that isn't included in two list

Tags: java, arrays

I need to provide a Java solution that given two list, a & b, that returns a value that is present in one list but not in another.

e.g. 
lists `a = [26, 13, 88, 9]`

lists `b = [26, 1, 8, 12]`

Comment: lists are int arrays?

Comment: `List` has a `removeAll(Collection)` method, this will remove duplicates .

Comment: @Berger - I don't think the OP wants to remove duplicates, just determine which value is in one but not the other

Comment: @QueenSvetlana I think Berger thinks of a new array that has the value of: a.removeAll(b)

Comment: You can make use of HashMap<> also in java, store all the elements of one list in hashmap and then iterate through the other list and check whether they are in hasmap or not

Comment: @QueenSvetlana yes they are

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  SO is not a codewriting service.

Comment: Duplicate question (search first next time?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590677/how-to-do-union-intersect-difference-and-reverse-data-in-java

Comment: @idmtwo I did search and couldn't find an answer. Clearly, I didn't search hard enough! Thank you all for your help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for those kind of operation it would be better to use collections,
the method [removeAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) will filter the data containers, from the doc:

> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the
>   specified collection (optional operation).

```
List<Integer> myVarListA = Arrays.asList(26, 13, 88, 9);
List<Integer> myVarListB = Arrays.asList(26, 1, 8, 12);
List<Integer> myVarListAcomplementB = new ArrayList<>(myVarListA);
List<Integer> myVarListBcomplementA = new ArrayList<>(myVarListB);
myVarListAcomplementB.removeAll(myVarListB);
myVarListBcomplementA.removeAll(myVarListA);
System.out.println("elements in A but no in B: " + myVarListAcomplementB);
System.out.println("elements in B but no in A: " + myVarListBcomplementA);
myVarListBcomplementA.addAll(myVarListAcomplementB);
System.out.println("both together: " + myVarListBcomplementA);
```

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner you are right, i misread something there... but now is ok... thanks anyway for the feedback!

Comment: This will return unique values from list A (13, 88, 9), I guess we should also grab unique values from list B (1, 8, 12 ).

Comment: @Berger do you mean in a reflective way? those that are in B but not in A?

Comment: Yes exactly, the question doesn't precise if we want unique values from both lists, but probably yes .

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is to calculate the intersection and remove that from the desired list. If you only want what is missing, you can optimize this a little by going a solution like ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ.

The great thing about this solution is that you can easily expand this to use 3+ sets/lists. Instead of A-B = diff or A-I(A,B)=diff, you can also do A-I(A,I(B,C)) to find what A is missing from the common set between A, B and C.

```
  public static <T> HashSet<T> intersection(Collection<T> a, Collection<T> b) {
        HashSet<T> aMinusB = new HashSet<>(a);
        aMinusB.removeAll(b);
        HashSet<T> common = new HashSet<>(a);
        common.removeAll(aMinusB);
        return common;
    }
```

Let's call the intersection set `Collection I = intersection(a,b);`.

Now if you want to find what is missing from list A that was in B:

```
new LinkedList(A).removeAll(I);//ordered and possibly containing duplicates
   OR
new ArrayList(A).removeAll(I);//ordered and possibly containing duplicates. Faster copy time, but slower to remove elements. Experiment with this and LinkedList for speed.
   OR
new LinkedHashSet<T>(a).removeAll(I);//ordered and unique
   OR
new HashSet<T>(a).removeAll(I);//unique and no order
```

Also, this question is effectively duplicate of [How to do union, intersect, difference and reverse data in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590677/how-to-do-union-intersect-difference-and-reverse-data-in-java)

Comment: @Idmtwo thank you. I'm new to this so apologies if this question is already on SO

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
a.removeAll(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply parse the second list and add unique elements to the first, delete others.

```
for (Integer elem : secondList)
  if (firstList.contains(elem))
    firstList.remove(elem);
  else
    firstList.add(elem);
```

In `firstList` you will have the values present only in one of the lists.