# How return sublist of items in first list that not exist in second list?

Tags: java, android, collections

Android 4.4

suppose I has 2 lists. 
I need to return sublist of items in first list that not contain in second list.

E.g:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] - [1,2,3,4,5] -> return []

[1,2,3,4,5] - [1,22,3,4,5] -> return [2]

[1,2,3,4,5] - [6,7,8,9,10] -> return [1,2,3,4,5]

[1,2,3,4,5] - [1,2,3,4,5,6] -> return []

[1,2,3,4,5] - [6,7,8,9,2] -> return [1,3,4,5]
```

How I can do this simple?
I can write custom java method to do this. But maybe already exist any good solution.

I need this because I need to remove all items from first list that not contain in second list.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I need to remove all items from first list that not contain in second list

Comment: Try to *remove all*

Comment: Yeah I get that. What have *YOU* tried to solve *YOUR* problem?

Comment: I use DB and if I first remove ALL items from first list it's start long DB operation. I need delete ONLY not exist items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do union, intersect, difference and reverse data in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590677/how-to-do-union-intersect-difference-and-reverse-data-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [<kbd>List.removeAll(Collection)</kbd>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) **:**

```
List<Integer> listFirst = ...;
List<Integer> listSecond = ...;

List<Integer> listThird = new ArrayList<>(listFirst);// use of 3rd list to keep the 2 others
listThird.removeAll(listSecond);
```