# Optimization (in terms of speed )

Tags: multithreading

is there any other way to optimize this code.  Anyone can come up with better way because this is taking lot of time in main code.   Thanks alot;)

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    List<String> dup = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> nondup = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String num : nums) {
        String x= num;
        String result = x.toLowerCase();
        if (hmap.containsKey(result)) {
            hmap.put(result, hmap.get(result) + 1);
        }
        else {
            hmap.put(result,1);
        }
    }
    for(String num:nums){
        int count= hmap.get(num.toLowerCase());
        if (count == 1){
            nondup.add(num);
        }
        else{
            dup.add(num);
        }
    }
```

output:
[A/tea, C/SEA.java, C/clock, aep, aeP, C/SEA.java]

Dups: [C/SEA.java, aep, aeP, C/SEA.java]

nondups: [A/tea, C/clock]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590677/how-to-do-union-intersect-difference-and-reverse-data-in-java) might help.

Comment: Instead of `if (hmap.containsKey(result)) { hmap.put(result, hmap.get(result) + 1); } else { hmap.put(result,1);  }` you can use `hmap.merge(result, 1, Integer::sum);` But since you don’t care about the actual number, but only whether it’s more than one, you can use a `Boolean` instead of `Integer` in the first place: `HashMap<String, Boolean> hmap = new HashMap<>(); List<String> dup = new ArrayList<>(), nondup = new ArrayList<>(); for(String num: nums) { hmap.merge(num.toLowerCase(), false, (a,b) -> true); } for(String num: nums) { (hmap.get(num.toLowerCase())? nondup: dup).add(num); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much time is "a lot of time"?  Is your input bigger than what you've actually shown us?

You *could* parallelize this with something like `Arrays.parallelStream(nums).collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(k -> k, Collectors.counting())`, which would get you a `Map<String, Long>`, but that would only speed up your code if you have a *lot* of input, which it doesn't look like you have right now.

You could parallelize the next step, if you liked, like so:

```
Map<String, Long> counts = Arrays.parallelStream(nums)
   .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(k -> k, Collectors.counting());
Map<Boolean, List<String>> hasDup =
   counts.entrySet().parallelStream()
     .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
        entry -> entry.getValue() > 1,
        Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));

List<String> dup = hasDup.get(true);
List<String> nodup = hasDup.get(false);
```

Comment: Hey @Louis - is there any way to make changes to second part: Map<Boolean, List<String>> hasDup such that it gives the output like Dups: [C/SEA.java, aep, aeP, C/SEA.java] nondups: [A/tea, C/clock]

Comment: @Emmef  Here the code gives output like: Dups: [c/sea.java, aep] nondups: [a/tea,c/clock]

Answer (score 0):

The algorithms in the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71669200/4121151) can speed up execution using multiple threads.

This can theoretically reduce the processing time with a factor of *M*, where *M* is the maximum number of threads that your system can run concurrently. However, as *M* is a constant number, this does not change the order of complexity, which therefore remains *O(N)*.

At a glance, I do not see a way to solve your problem in less than *O(N)*, I am afraid.